# Typescript how to constrain function parameter with the properties of an interface

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Hi guys I'm trying to find a way to constrain a function parameter, so it only takes "strings" constrained to an interface properties as I did in function validate fields:

**Note:** This is just the definition typescript code to make the question simpler.

**index.d.ts**

```
export interface FieldErrors {
  errors: Array<FieldError>;
}

export type FieldsErrors<TForm> = {
  [k in keyof TForm]: FieldErrors;
}

export interface ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm> { (fieldsErrors: FieldsErrors<TForm>, values: TForm): void; };

export interface FormShape<TForm> {
  getFieldValue(fieldName: 'documentNumber' | 'userName'): void; // HOW TO FIX THIS
  validateFields(callback: ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm>): void;
  validateFields(fieldsNames: Array<string>, callback: ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm>): void;
}
```

**example.ts**

```
interface SignupForm {
    documentNumber: number;
    userName: string;
}

const testForm = <FormShape<SignupForm>>{};

testForm.validateFields((values) => {
    console.log(values.documentNumber); // OK
    console.log(values.userName); // OK
    console.log(values.other); // ERROR
});

// THIS SHOULD BE FIXED
const documentNumber = testForm.getFieldValue('documentNumber');
```

As you can see, I'm able to constrain the parameter **fieldsErrors** type of the **validateFields** callback, but I need to fix the function **getFieldValue** to only accept a "correct" field name based on the interface properties, and also return the correct type based on the interface type nor void.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please post code not pictures!

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir done ! :)

Comment: Just for future reference, it'd be nice if this were pared down to a more minimal example; a lot of the code in the example wasn't really relevant to the question being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `keyof T` in mapped types, but `keyof T` is a type in itself that can be used in any context a type is accepted. `keyof T` represents a union of all keys of the type `T`, which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

To get the return type to be the same as the type of the field, you need to add a type parameter to `getFieldValue` and use a type query to return the type of that field.

```
export interface FormShape<TForm> {
    getFieldValue<K extends keyof TForm>(fieldName: K): TForm[K]; // Accepts only keys of TForm and returns the value of teh field
    validateFields(callback: ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm>): void;
    validateFields(fieldsNames: Array<string>, callback: ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm>): void;
}
```

With regard to array there could be several approaches. If you just want simple arrays, you can make fieldname an array.

```
export interface FormShape<TForm> {
    getFieldValue<K extends keyof TForm>(...fieldName: K[]): TForm[K][] ; 
    validateFields(callback: ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm>): void;
    validateFields(fieldsNames: Array<string>, callback: ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm>): void;
}
```

This does have the disadvantage that you loose type safety on each index, ideally we want to take in a tuple and return a tuple. To do this we can add several overloads:

```
export interface FormShape<TForm> {
    getFieldValue<K extends keyof TForm, K1 extends keyof TForm, K2 extends keyof TForm>(fieldName: [K, K1, K2]): [TForm[K], TForm[K1], TForm[K2]]; 
    getFieldValue<K extends keyof TForm, K1 extends keyof TForm>(fieldName: [K, K1]): [TForm[K], TForm[K1]]; 
    getFieldValue<K extends keyof TForm>(fieldName: [K]): [TForm[K]]; 
    validateFields(callback: ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm>): void;
    validateFields(fieldsNames: Array<string>, callback: ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm>): void;
}
```

Also a good option is to not return an array, but rather an object containing the keys passed in as arguments:

```
export interface FormShape<TForm> {
    getFieldValues<K extends keyof TForm>(...fieldName: K[]): { [P in K]: TForm[P] }; // Accepts only keys of TForm and returns the value of teh field
    validateFields(callback: ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm>): void;
    validateFields(fieldsNames: Array<string>, callback: ValidateFieldsCallback<TForm>): void;
}

//Usage
const documentNumber = testForm.getFieldValues('documentNumber', 'userName'); //{documentNumber: number;userName: string;}
```

Comment: Okey but how would you change the return type VOID to be the same as the property on the interface ?

Comment: @DavidNoreña Wops, missed that, it's 6AM in my neck of the woods coffee hasn't kicked in yet :) fixed

Comment: 6am BUT YOU STILL ROCK ! awesome thank you so much !

Comment: What if I want to add a getFieldValues(fieldsNames) could be an array ?

Comment: @DavidNoreña I'll add an array version shortly

Comment: @DavidNoreña yeah that's the simple way, I would go with tuples though as you do know that the type of key 0 is going to be the type of the field passed in in on the 0 index.